# Python with MySql "SAWarning: Unicode type received non-unicode bind param value" error

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, sqlalchemy

Before asking this question I've checked other posts on the similar. The answers provided simply suppressed the warning, instead of proposing a remedy.

I have a web application written with Python + Flask, which handles async requests sent with jquery in the unicode format. 
`Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8`

Here is an example of the data sent from my web browser to the server. The data can be a mix of latin and non-latin characters. I've noticed that non-latin characters are codified but latin are not.

> body: "Ð¥Ð¾Ñ‡Ñƒ ÑÑ…Ð¾Ð´Ð¸Ñ‚ÑŒ Ð½Ð° #Ñ„Ð¸Ð»ÑŒÐ¼ ÐšÐ°Ñ€Ñ‚ÐµÐ»ÑŒ.
>   ÐÐµÑÐ¼Ð¾Ñ‚Ñ€Ñ Ð½Ð° Ð¿Ð¾ÑÑ€ÐµÐ´ÑÑ‚Ð²ÐµÐ½Ð½Ñ‹Ðµ Ð¾Ñ‚Ð·Ñ‹Ð²Ñ‹,
>   Ñ„Ð¸Ð»ÑŒÐ¼ Ð´Ð¾Ð»Ð¶ÐµÐ½ Ð±Ñ‹Ñ‚ÑŒ Ð¿Ñ€Ð¸ÐºÐ¾Ð»ÑŒÐ½Ñ‹Ð¼. Ð’Ð¾Ñ‚ ÐµÐ³Ð¾
>   Ð¾Ð¿Ð¸ÑÐ°Ð½Ð¸Ðµ
>   http://www.allocine.fr/film/fichefilm_gen_cfilm=202971.html"

Here is the definition of my MySqlAlchemy class

```
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.Unicode(1024))
```

Now, when I try to submit the data to the database I receive the error below:

> SAWarning: Unicode type received non-unicode bind para m value.
>   param.append(processorskey)

In between I'm using Flask-Restful component to handle HTTP requests:

```
class PostListApi(Resource):
    decorators = [login_required]
    def post(self):
        body=request.json['body']
        post = Post(body=body)
        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()
```

The question is how should I handle the data correctly on the server side thus to make sure that non-unicode characters are not being written into the DB?

Comment: It's ok that ascii is left as is, [ASCII text are valid UTF-8-encoded Unicode as well.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). How do you handle your data inbetween?

Comment: alko: I've updated to the post

Comment: What python version are you using? There's a big difference in how Unicode is handled between Python 2 and 3!

Answer (score 3):

You can simply force the body to unicode.

```
class PostListApi(Resource):
    decorators = [login_required]
    def post(self):
        body=request.json['body']
        post = Post(body=unicode(body))
        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()
```